# Do jQuery ajax calls using JSONP need to be modified (or avoided) due to Rosetta Flash exploit

Tags: jquery, ajax, flash, security, jsonp

The fix for the Rosetta Flash exploit is for a service to prepend an empty comment (/**/) to the callback function invocation.

Instead of returning:

```
my_callback({key1:"value1",key2:"value2"})
```

it must now produce:

```
/**/my_callback({key1:"value1",key2:"value2"})
```

If we're using jQuery ($.ajax) to make the request, do we need to prepend the empty comment to the jsonCallback parameter in the request?

```
jsonpCallback: "/**/my_callback"
```

Somehow I don't think that will solve the exploit.

Comment: Let me know if you need any further detail adding to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, the fix is something the server should do regardless of what the client asks for.

The comment characters won't change the name of the callback that the script will call.

Answer (score 0):

See these slides for some [possible mitigations](http://miki.it/RosettaFlash/RosettaFlash.pdf).

These protections are all server side as the attack leverages the JSONP callback in order to reflect the encoded flash file to the victim's client. The attacker's script would be sending the encoded Flash to the end-point, not your `js`, which is why you do not need to alter your jQuery request.